# Deleting ASP.NET Identity users using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

Is it ok to delete records from [ASP.NET identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=vs0) tables `AspNetUSers`, `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` **directly** from SQL Server using [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL)? The ASP.NET Core app is using only these three identity tables other `AspNet...` tables are empty.

**UPDATE**:

Why we want to do it directly through T-SQL since app has several users (with one role) and client wants to get rid of all the users quickly in one shot.

Comment: Sure you can, but I wonder, why would you want to do this? Why don't you use the storage provider to take care of this?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Good question. I've added an **UPDATE** section to answer it for other readers' benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to delete rows from AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles or AspNetUserRoles.
Because IdentityServer does the same. 
For example check the SQL statements which are generated when deleting a user through the UserStore class.

Comment: Do you have sources that support this statement or is it just your opinion?

Comment: The source are the generated SQL statements which are executed when you create/delete users through the UserStore.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant. Are there credible and/or official sources that you can link in your answer? Why is it ok to delete rows?

Comment: At least you could have added a link. But I do not see how this answers the question. You are missing the part 'directly from SQL Server using T-SQL'.

Comment: There's no link where you can see a SQL statement. therefore I do not understand what you're looking for. Take a look at the UserStore class and check the generated and executed SQL statements. I can't see a reason why it shouldn't be ok to do the same.